# Enviar requisições POST pelo navegador ou outro programa

Tags: google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, requisição

Pelo navegador é possível somente realizar gets introduzindo a url no navegador, teria alguma forma de fazer requisições POST pelo navegador ou outro aplicativo, isso facilitara bastante a minha quando for dar manutenção no servidor. Estava dando uma olhada e é possível pelo propt de comando usando o `curl` mas não consegui me adaptar muito bem.

O motivo disso, basicamente estou fazendo o servidor primeiro pois o designer ainda não terminou de desenhar as tela, por isso ja gostaria de ir deixando pronto o meu servidor pronto.

Comment: Ficou um pouco confuso sua pergunta, mas acho que o PostMan poderá lhe ajudar. Procure o plugin para o chorme, nele vc pode enviar todos os tipos de requisições e testar serviços como REST.

Comment: Cara você salvou minha noite, era exatamente isso que estava procurando, não sabia da existência desse plugin, obrigado

Comment: Pode usar o Postman, ele agora tem uma versão para Windows / Mac.
se for SOAP ainda tem como opção o SOAPUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enviar requisições com CURL não é nada trabalhoso. Veja um exemplo:

## 1 - Enviando requisição com CURL com um JSON

O exemplo abaixo faz uma requisição POST em um host passando um JSON e fazendo uma autenticação básica.

```
curl -X POST --data "@nome_do_arquivo.json" -H "Content-
Type:application/json" 
    -H "Authorization:key=AIzaSyAdb8MI_4j1_CSiG-GSfjkO84CZ06P9VyA" 
http://meuservidor_.com.br
```

**-X POST**: Indica que será feita uma requisição POST

**-H**: Adicionando uma linha ao cabeçalho onde o conteúdo é um JSON

**"Authorization:key=**: Autenticação básica

> Para mais informações use curl --help

## 2 - Usando o POSTMAN

Outra alternativa é usar o **PostMan**, plug-in do chrome. Pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)

Inclusive você também pode usar PostMan para outros fins como testar um servidor Restful.

Answer (score 0):

**Na Console do Chrome:**

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/execute", {
  "body": null,
  "method": "POST"
});
```

Ou

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/execute", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site"
  },
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});
```